# Invoke Safari Content Blocker extension only when certain conditions are met?

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, ios9, safari-content-blocker

Is it possible to get a Safari Content Blocker extension in iOS 9 to be invoked only when certain conditions are met - e.g. if it is within a certain time period (let's say you want to block trackers from 9-5 but not in the evening), or if you are on cellular? I know that in theory this could be done manually in the Settings app. But is there a way to make it automated, so you can just leave the content blocker on all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i have done this. in my case there is a switch in the app so user can disable the content blocker without going to Setting app.
I have done it by simply updating the json file at APP Group Container path whenever user disable the switch.
In my case i am reading all blocker rules from blockerJson file from APP Main Bundle and put these rules in an array.then write this array of rules to `BlockerJsonFile.json` file at App group identifier container.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:YOUR_APP_GROUP_IDENTIFIER] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"BlockerJsonFile.json"]
```

and when the user disable the switch then i update `BlockerJsonFile.json` file and make it empty and reload the content blocker using (`SFContentBlockerManager.reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifier`).